How to set the labels of a pie chart to avoid overlapping using ggplot2
I was trying to plot a pie char using ggplot2. The code is pasted as following
df <- data.frame(
  category = LETTERS[1 : 14],
  count = c(86, 2, 6, 315, 98, 140, 48, 167, 226, 269, 2, 70, 3, 112)
)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = "", y = count, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = count), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)

And the output is shown as the following picture:

May I know how to set the labels to avoid overlapping? Thank you :)

The best way is not to use a pie chart.  There are other options including a simple table of values. It is difficult to get a sense of scale from the pie wedges.

For small wedges, you could consider combining them into an "other" category as in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78444478/how-to-draw-pie-chart-with-a-descending-order-and-showing-only-the-top-8-portion/78446448#78446448

Try the following, I have been using this method in some older versions
# Install ggrepel 
install.packages("ggrepel")

# Load the library
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(
  category = LETTERS[1:14],
  count = c(86, 2, 6, 315, 98, 140, 48, 167, 226, 269, 2, 70, 3, 112)
)

# Plot the pie chart with non-overlapping labels
ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = count, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = count),
                  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                  box.padding = 0.5,
                  point.padding = 0.5,
                  segment.color = 'grey50') +
  theme_void()


